# Name for LDC: Lebesgue?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, math-history

Is there also a name associated to the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem like Beppo-Levi or Fatou? Would Lebesgue be reasonable? Who did originally prove it?

Comment: @Clarinetist: Is this question rhetoric?

Comment: I believe that it likely is attributable to Lebesgue, and the Wikipedia article seems to do so implicitly with the slight change in nomenclature: Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.  However let me see if I can find something in the way of a definitive reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is due to Lebesgue. Bogachev (Measure Theory, Volume 1, Springer, page 428) writes:

> "The Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem in the general case (with an integegrable majorant) was given by him [Lebesgue] [...]"

The specific reference that is given is (the link leads to a free copy):

> [H. Lebesgue, Sur la méthode de M. Goursat pour la résolution de l'équation de Fredholm, Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, 36 (1908), 3-19.](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1908__36__3_1)

Comment: The dominated convergence result may have appeared earlier, in Lebesgue's thesis (published 1902).  I must trudge to the library, it seems, to find a copy of Hawkin's [Lebesgue's Theory of Integration](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CHEL-282-H) for further details.

Comment: There were *weaker* versions earlier, as implied by the formulation "in the general case." Specifically, Lebesgue's "Leçons sur l'integration" (1904) already contains a result for $f_n$ uniformly bounded (and something might well be in his thesis already); in the paper I link to earlier results of the form are mentioned in passing when the result is formulated (page 12). But, I do not know the history in full detail. However, I interpreted the question as asking for what typically goes *now* as Dominated Convergence theorem, which is in the paper I link to, but *not yet* in his "Leçons".